# IdentityServer4 Duplicate Scopes

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I've got a REST webservice that we to deploy n-number of clients.  The same app is deployed, just with diffent configuration.  We have a web frontend website that talks to these REST webservice instances.  A user auths with IdentityServer4 the instance, uses the front end, which calls to the back end webservice instances, passing the token to it.

I need to prevent a token retrieved that grants access to webservice-X from being used to access webservice-Y.  Ideally, I'd have an ApiResource defined for each of the deployed clients with the same scopes.   I'm getting the following error message when trying authenticate:

> Duplicate API scopes found. This is an invalid configuration. Use different names for API scopes. Scopes found: PaymentApi, DocumentApi

Is there a way that I can disable this duplicate check?  Is there another way to configure everything to accomplish this?

Part of my configuration:

```
            new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "WebService-X",
                DisplayName = "WebService-X",
                Description = "Client Api residing on customer-X network",
                Enabled = true,
                Scopes = new List<Scope>()
                {
                    new Scope()
                    {
                        Name = "PaymentApi",
                        DisplayName = "PaymentApi",
                        ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                    },
                    new Scope()
                    {
                        Name = "DocumentApi",
                        DisplayName = "DocumentApi",
                        ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                    }
                },
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("fdzxGSDFHY)GSFD*U)DIS:LGJSLKFDJGG".Sha256())
                },
            },
            new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "WebService-Y",
                DisplayName = "WebService-Y",
                Description = "Client Api residing on customer-Y network",
                Enabled = true,
                Scopes = new List<Scope>()
                {
                    new Scope()
                    {
                        Name = "PaymentApi",
                        DisplayName = "PaymentApi",
                        ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                    },
                    new Scope()
                    {
                        Name = "DocumentApi",
                        DisplayName = "DocumentApi",
                        ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                    }
                },
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("fdzxGSDFHY)GSDFS$#%#$LKFDJGG".Sha256())
                },
            },
```

I want to avoid something like this because it doesn't scale well:

```
                new ApiResource
                {
                    Name = "WebService-X",
                    DisplayName = "WebService-X",
                    Description = "Client Api residing on customer-X network",
                    Enabled = true,
                    Scopes = new List<Scope>()
                    {
                        new Scope()
                        {
                            Name = "PaymentApi-X",
                            DisplayName = "PaymentApi-X",
                            ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                        },
                        new Scope()
                        {
                            Name = "DocumentApi-X",
                            DisplayName = "DocumentApi-X",
                            ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                        }
                    },
                    ApiSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("fdzxGSDFHY)GSFD*U)DIS:LGJSLKFDJGG".Sha256())
                    },
                },
                new ApiResource
                {
                    Name = "WebService-Y",
                    DisplayName = "WebService-Y",
                    Description = "Client Api residing on customer-Y network",
                    Enabled = true,
                    Scopes = new List<Scope>()
                    {
                        new Scope()
                        {
                            Name = "PaymentApi-Y",
                            DisplayName = "PaymentApi-Y",
                            ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                        },
                        new Scope()
                        {
                            Name = "DocumentApi-Y",
                            DisplayName = "DocumentApi-Y",
                            ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                        }
                    },
                    ApiSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("fdzxGSDFHY)GSDFS$#%#$LKFDJGG".Sha256())
                    },
                },
```

Comment: Scopes must have unique names.

Answer (score 0):

This verification is done via an extension method within [IResourceStoreExtensions](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Extensions/IResourceStoreExtensions.cs). There isn't way to override this behavior, as the [intended design](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/api_resource.html?highlight=scopes) is at least one unique API scope for each API resource.

In your particular situation, you would have to configure scopes and API resources for each tenant as they are separate resources.

Speculatively, if you had a centralized resource, one which utilized your customer endpoints as a kind of service infrastructure, you could instead indicate your intended tenant as part of the request and use scope claims to determine if the request is permissible.